# Was Allah compared to a rock?

Tags: quran, allah

A [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/17730/is-reference-to-god-as-a-rock-unique-to-judeo-christian-usage) poped up in Christian SE asking if God in other religion was compared to a rock. I wonder if in Quran Allah is compared to a rock?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Chapter 112, Al-Ikhlas (The Purity) describes Allah as follows:

```
112:1 Say, "He is Allah , [who is] One,
112:2 Allah , the Eternal Refuge.
112:3 He neither begets nor is born,
112:4 Nor is there to Him any equivalent."
```

This is the message throughout the Quran. Allah is not comparable to anything or anyone.